# With the help of onTouchlistener my image is moving but i want it to stop at a particular position so that i can perform some action on it

Tags: android

With the help of onTouchlistener my image is moving but i want it to stop at a particular position so that i can perform some action on it ie on clicking to exact position i want some pop up to come to another Activity to perform

this is the coding which i have done . Is there any method of ontouchlistner so tha i can perform my desired operations

```
    ...
    ...        
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float xdiff = Math.abs( x - event.getX());
            float ydiff =  Math.abs( y - event.getY());
            if( xdiff < 23 || ydiff < 23 ){
                isStarted = true;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(isStarted)
            {
                x = event.getX() - img.getWidth()/2;
                y = event.getY() - img.getHeight()/2;
                Log.v("X:" + x, "Y: " + y);
                this.invalidate();
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            isStarted = false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem? I understand that you want the image to stop moving.. but if you do not touch it it will not move.. so what are you trying to achieve? Where do you want to stop it and when?

Comment: Although My image is moving but i want that image come to a particular position then after that a new activity or popup strikes up.

Comment: What is this position.. can you provide more details? is it some point  (x,y)?

Comment: Actually Sir i am performing some task in which there is a door with no door knob and the user make the door knob slide to the place where door is present at particular X,Y position . After knob reach to particular position i want it to perform some action that is to open a activity or popup . I am able to make it slide but wont able to make it perform some action after it reaches the particular position .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, here is a general solution that you can use:

```
    ...
    ...        
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float xdiff = Math.abs( x - event.getX());
            float ydiff =  Math.abs( y - event.getY());
            if( xdiff < 23 || ydiff < 23 ){
                isStarted = true;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(isStarted)
            {
                x = event.getX() - img.getWidth()/2;
                y = event.getY() - img.getHeight()/2;
                Log.v("X:" + x, "Y: " + y);
                this.invalidate();
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(isStarted) 
            {
                Rect imgRect = new Rect();
                img.getGlobalVisibleRect(imgRect);

                // compare if imgRect is close enough to correct place
                // if: imgRect.left, imgRect.top are near door knob position
                //      then: open dialog/ start activity
            }
            isStarted = false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically, after `ACTION_UP` compare the position of the `img` and see if it is close to the required position `(X,Y)` and then perform action..

I can give a more specific solution if you can provide me how you init/draw the door and the knob on the view..

Comment: I am still not able to get the desired result . Here is my Code ''

Comment: I have posted above you can see

Answer (score 0):

'public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{

```
MySurface msurface;
float x,y,sX,sY,fX,fY;

Bitmap bt,plus;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    msurface=new MySurface(this);
    msurface.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x=0;
    y=0;
    sX=0;
    sY=0;
    fX=0;
    fY=0;

    bt=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hndle);
    plus=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gbut);
    setContentView(msurface);
}
protected void onPause() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    msurface.pause();
}

protected void onResume() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    msurface.resume();

}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    x=event.getX();
    y=event.getY();


    switch(event.getAction())
    {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        sX=event.getX();
        sY=event.getY();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        fX=event.getX();
        fY=event.getY();
        break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable 
{

SurfaceHolder ourHolder;

```
Thread ourTh=null;

boolean isRunning=false;

public MySurface(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    ourHolder=getHolder();
    ourTh=new Thread(this);
    ourTh.start();

}

public void pause() //bringin android games
{
    isRunning=false;
    while(true)
    {
        try 
        {
            ourTh.join();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    ourTh=null;
}
public void resume()
{
    isRunning=true;
}


@Override
public void run()
{
    while(isRunning)
    {
        if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        Canvas canvas=ourHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150); //backgroung color hai
        if(x!=0 && y!=0)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bt, x-(bt.getWidth()/2), y-(bt.getHeight()/2), null);

        }
        if(sX==256 && y==27)
        {

            canvas.drawBitmap(bt, x-(bt.getWidth()/2), y-(bt.getHeight()/2), null);
            Intent a=new Intent(MainActivity.this,dusari.class);
        }
        /*if(fX!=0 && fY!=0)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bt, x-(bt.getWidth()/2), y-(bt.getHeight()/2), null);

        }*/
        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    }

}
```

Comment: OK two problems: 1) the code you posted previously looks very different from this, 2) this code has other problems, doesn't work when i try to run it.. empty screen

Comment: yes because that code was not working so i have changed the code . this code too have problem . how can i manage this ??